# SQL Server query on two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a SQL Server database with two tables, table 1 lists membership records and table 2 lists the names for each membership record. There can be more than one person in table 2 per record in table 1.

- table_1.MembershipNumber
- table_1.MemberType
- table_1.StartDate
- table_2.MembershipNumber
- table_2.FirstName
- table_2.LastName
- table_2.Age

I would like to create a view which filters out records in table 1 where the age of anyone in table 2 is over the age of, say, 50.

Comment: You should NOT store a person's age. You should instead store their birthdate and calculate their age when you need it. Otherwise your data is constantly stale.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Membership]
  AS 
Select t.MembershipNumber ,tt.FirstName,tt.LastName 
    from MembershipNumber_table_1 t
    INNER JOIN  MembershipNumber_table_2 tt
    ON t.MembershipNumber = tt.MembershipNumber 
        AND MemberType = 'A'
    WHERE (DATEDIFF(yy,MembershipNumber_table_2.Age,GetDate()) -
CASE WHEN((MONTH(MembershipNumber_table_2.Age)*100 + DAY(MembershipNumber_table_2.Age)) > (MONTH(GetDate())*100 + DAY(GetDate()))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>50
GO
```

OR

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, MembershipNumber_table_2.Age, GETDATE())>50
```